# XNA rotation over given vector

Tags: xna, rotation, 3d

I'm newbie in XNA, so sorry about the simple question, but I can't find any solution.

I've got simple model (similar to flat cuboid), which I cannot change (model itself). I would like to create rotate animation. In this particular problem, my model is just a cover of piano. However, the axis over which I'm going to rotate is covered by cover's median. As a result, my model is rotating like a turbine, instead of opening and closing.

I would like to rotate my object over given "line". I found `Matrix.CreateLookAt(currentPosition, dstPosition, Vector.Up);` method, but still don't know how o combine rotation with such matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Matrix.CreateLookAt is meant for use in a camera, not for manipulating models (although I'm sure some clever individuals who understand what sort of matrix it creates have done so).

What you are wanting to do is rotate your model around an arbitrary axis in space.  It's not an animation (those are created in 3D modeling software, not the game), it's a transformation.  Transformations are methods by which you can move, rotate and scale a model, and are obviously the crux of 3D game graphics.

For your problem, you want to rotate this flat piece around its edge, yes?  To do this, you will combine translation and axis rotation.

First, you want to move the model so the edge you want to rotate around intersects with the origin.  So, if the edge was a straight line in the Z direction, it would be perfectly aligned with the Z axis and intersecting 0,0,0.  To do this you will need to know the dimensions of your model.  Once you have those, create a Matrix:

```
Matrix originTranslation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-modelWidth / 2f, 0, 0))
```

(This assumes a square model.  Manipulate the Vector3 until the edge you want is intersecting the origin)

Now, we want to do the rotating.  This depends on the angle of your edge.  If your model is a square and thus the edge is straight forward in the Z direction, we can just rotate around Vector3.Forward.  However, if your edge is angled (as I imagine a piano cover to be), you will have to determine the angle yourself and create a Unit Vector with that same angle.  Now you will create another Matrix:

```
Matrix axisRotation = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(myAxis, rotation)
```

where myAxis is the unit vector which represents the angle of the edge, and rotation is a float for the number of radians to rotate.

That last bit is the key to your 'animation'.  What you are going to want to do is vary that float amount depending on how much time has passed to create an 'animation' of the piano cover opening over time.  Of course you will want to clamp it at an upper value, or your cover will just keep rotating.

Now, in order to actually transform your cover model, you must multiply its world matrix by the two above matrices, in order.

```
pianoCover.World *= originTranslation * axisRotation;
```

then if you wish you can translate the cover back so that its center is at the origin (by multiplying by a Transform Matrix with the Vector3 values negative of what you first had them), and then subsequently translate your cover to wherever it needs to be in space using another Transform Matrix to that point.

So, note how matrices are used in 3D games.  A matrix is created using the appropriate Matrix method in order to create qualities which you desire (translation, rotation around and axis, scale, etc).  You make a matrix for each of these properties.  Then you multiply them in a specific order (**order matters in matrix multiplication**) to transform your model as you wish.  Often, as seen here, these transformations are intermediate in order to get the desired effect (we could not simply move the cover to where we wanted it then rotate it around its edge; we had to move the edge to the origin, rotate, move it back, etc).

Working with matrices in 3D is pretty tough.  In fact, I may not have gotten all that right (I hope by now I know that well enough, but...).  The more practice you get, the better you can judge how to perform tasks like this.  I would recommend reading tutorials on the subject.  Any tutorial that covers 3D in XNA will have this topic.

In closing, though, if you know 3D Modeling software well enough, I would probably suggest you just make an actual animation of a piano and cover opening and closing and use that animated model in your game, instead of using models for both the piano and cover and trying to keep them together.